# Header Location after file_put_contents

Tags: php, redirect, fwrite, php-7

I try to read a constant from a file and be able to change this constant on demand.

So when this constant need to be written (for this example through a GET), right after I would like to reload the page to have the correct value.

But after the reload, even if my file contains the new value, it seems that the constant is still defined to the old one.

If I put a sleep before the header(Location) everything works fine. Is there a solution without the sleep, and why?

Here is the example file:

```
<?php
  include_once 'toto.php';
  if (isset($_GET['test'])) {
    $file = "<?php const TOTO = '$_GET[test]'; ?>";
    file_put_contents('toto.php', $file);
    // sleep(3);
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
  }
  echo TOTO;
?>
```

I tried to replace the file_put_contents by fopen+fwrite+fflush+fclose without more success.

Comment: *"be able to change this constant on demand."* Do you understand the concept of **"constant"**?

Comment: I agree with @ʰᵈˑ - using `const` for something you intend to change is not good. I've had to maintain systems in the past that were written this way, and it sucks. It looks like you're writing a config system for your app? If so, consider using either plain PHP variables (see the config files for apps like Joomla and Wordpress, both of which allow you to update the config from within the application), a PHP array (see Laravel's config for any example), or better yet, save the config in a non PHP format like JSON or an ini file that can be easily loaded and parsed using built-in PHP functions.

Comment: Also, it's important to note that if `$_GET['test']` contains any quote marks, it will cause toto.php to be invalid. Or worse, it could be used to inject any arbitrary PHP code into your system. I get that this a test program to prove the concept, but it's a significant enough issue that it's worth raising.

Comment: @Simba I've explained this in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39124190/3000179) also  (both of your comments have been addressed in my answer) `:)`

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ heh, I had the page on the screen before your answer was posted. I didn't see your answer until after I'd commented.

Answer (score 0):

The above code working fine for me.

What your index.php contains?

Comment: So, when you're calling http://localhost/index.php?test=42 it display 42 ? And then if you call http://localhost/index.php?test=43 it display 43 ?

For me except for the first time (when the file wasn't existing and is created) it always display the previous value.

I think that the write is not totally done when the redirect is called, but I don't know why.

Comment: check if toto.php is writable

Comment: Yes it is, and the content of the file is always up to date and correct.

Answer (score 0):

#### Concept breaking

The concept of a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) is that throughout the application it doesn't change its value. You're breaking the principle of a constant.

#### Insecure

Also, since the constant is defined with user input, and written to a file, we can very easily hijack your server with any malicious code we want. Ie:

```
http://localhost/index.php?test=42%27;eval($_GET[%27hack%27]);%3F>
```

Then we can append to the query string anything we want executing.

```
http://localhost/index.php?hack=echo%20shell_exec(%27cat%20%2Fetc%2Fpasswd%27)
```

And viola, we have your `/etc/passwd` file. From there, we could get your `/etc/shadow` file and hijack your entire server. We could create more backdoors to your server - pretty much do *anything* to your server by passing our commands to the `hack` query string parameter.

#### The fix

To modify your script so that it doesn't break this concept, or you have no race condition on writing the new value to the file and reading, **consider using a [cookie or a session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)** (both are unique to the client; cookies are editable by the client, sessions generally aren't (the session ID is, but the value bound to that session ID isn't)).

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include_once 'toto.php'; //or put session_start(); at the top of this file
  if (isset($_GET['test'])) {
     $_SESSION['TOTO'] = $_GET['test']; //Do some sanitation here since it's user input.
     header('Location: index.php');
     exit;
  }
```

Now to read this, simply use `$_SESSION['TOTO'];`.

Though, since you've mentioned this should be a global configuration (ie: throughout the entire application and for all users), then use an [ini file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) or [database](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php).

Comment: Except that is in order to set a global configuration for all users (not only the one who's changing it) on the site. It can be only modified by admin user, and would be one or twice a year.

Comment: If it is a global configuration, use an [ini file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) or [database](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php).

Comment: Dismissing the security concerns because "only modified by an admin user" isn't wise. If/when an admin account gets compromised (and because you're using user input with no sanitation, it could be likely you;re doing it elsewhere in your application so hijacking accounts *could* be easy), your entire system will be compromised - you are giving the ability to run shell/database/php commands to anyone!

Comment: Ok, I totally understand your point about constant and you're right.
Therefore this code I paste is only an example of the concept I would like to use (in a ini file, I agree with you) and that's also why there's no sanitation : to keep the problem the simplest possible. So the question is: why does TEST contains the previous value after header(Location), but the file contains the correct data?

Comment: @unicorn because you cannot redefine a constant. Look in your error_log and you'll see.

Comment: I do not have any error. I do not understand where I redefining a constant. I change the content of a file which is included each time index.php is loaded. Does header(Location) keep the define of previous constant? Is it not a fully new load of the page/script? Have you tested the script and having error?

Comment: I've misread. You're not redefining the constant, though you won't be able to read the value of `?test` until a new page load and until `file_put_contents()` has written. There may be a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) with writing to the file and redirecting.

Comment: As a workaround I could put the include _once after the if block. But my existential question is: as file_put_contents is a synchronous function and header(Location) performs a reload, why the variable (or constant) does not contain the correct value ? And moreover why is it working when I add a sleep(), as if file_put_contents was a asynchronous function and the sleep leaves it time to dump data before reload.

Comment: It would indicate a slow write to the file, ergo [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

Answer (score -1):

You can try putting this code -

```
<?php
include_once 'toto.php';
if (isset($_GET['test'])) {
    $file = "<?php const TOTO = '$_GET[test]'; ?>";
    if (file_put_contents('toto.php', $file)) {
        // sleep(3);
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
}
echo TOTO;
?>
```

With this code the header function will be called only if the constant is written to your file properly.

Also your issue may be occurring because the page is redirected before the write to toto.php is in progress.

Comment: yes indeed the reload is only needed if the constant has been written in the file.

I also think that the issue occurred because the page is redirected before the write to toto.php is not finished but I think that file_put_contents is a synchronous function so I don't understand why. Moreover the file_put_contents returns the correct number of bytes written...

Comment: This is highly insecure. Also broken conceptually (you cannot redefine a constant that has already been defined in the current runtime). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39124190/3000179) for a better understanding.

Comment: Thats write. The toto.php file is not being appended it re-written every time.